# Best way to performance image displaying in Qt

Tags: c++, performance, qt

I need display image with two requirements, it must be very fast (60-120 fps possible) and with low CPU performance overhead to displaying and draw primitives and scroll. I find some options, but I'm not sure witch will be the best.
I will avoiding copy Image. Just date feeder will write directly to image

1. Write custom QOpenGlWidget. Pros: no image copy, opengl backend. Cons: a lot of works, no scrolls implemented
2. Use QGraphicsView as standard. Pros: also opengl backend possible. Cons: please correct me if I miss but image is copy in stanard way.
3. QGraphicsView with repimplemented drawBackground function. Pros: no image copy, opengl backend. Cons: i don't know.

Could you show me solutions what I miss and help to choose best one?

Comment: I think for 60-120fps you'll probably want to use QOpenGLWidget and render the graphics yourself.  You're right, it's more work, but by the same token you'll have more control over what is drawn and when, which means you're more likely to be able to maintain your target frame rate.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I think that it depends on the rendering method the system is using. You have software and hardware rendering. If you use pure CPU power without any integrated or dedicated GPU, then you won't get a performance boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using [QGraphicsItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html) and reimplementing [QGraphicsItem::paint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#paint) which calls the [QPainter::drawImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage-4), will do what you want without hassles of doing OpenGL stuff between [QPainter::beginNativePainting()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#beginNativePainting) and [QPainter::endNativePainting()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#endNativePainting). Taking the former path (native paitings) is also another option if the call to [QPainter::drawImage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#drawImage-4) won't give your desired outcome.

```
void FastImageItem::paint(QPainter *painter,
                          const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                          QWidget *widget)
{
    painter->drawImage(image.rect, image, image.rect);
}
```

Obviously, you should implement [QGraphicsItem::boundingRect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#boundingRect) to return your image size.